# Can't see AWS ebs snapshot tags from another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have private snapshots in one account (source) that I have shared with another account (target). I am able to see the snapshots themselves from the target account, but the tags are not available, neither on the console nor via the cli.  This makes it impossible to filter for a desired snapshot from the target account.  For background, the user in the target account has the following policy in effect:

```
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*"
```

Here's an example of what I'm seeing; from the source account:

```
$ aws --region us-east-2 ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-ids snap-XXXXX
{
    "Snapshots": [
        {
            "Description": "snapshot for testing",
            "VolumeSize": 50,
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "test-snapshot",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "Encrypted": true,
            "VolumeId": "vol-XXXXX",
            "State": "completed",
            "KmsKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:XXXXX:key/mrk-XXXXX",
            "StartTime": "2022-04-19T18:29:36.069Z",
            "Progress": "100%",
            "OwnerId": "XXXXX",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-XXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

but from the target account

```
$ aws --region us-east-2 ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids 012345678900 --snapshot-ids snap-11111111111111111
{
    "Snapshots": [
        {
            "Description": "snapshot for testing",
            "VolumeSize": 50,
            "Encrypted": true,
            "VolumeId": "vol-22222222222222222",
            "State": "completed",
            "KmsKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:012345678900:key/mrk-00000000000000000000000000000000",
            "StartTime": "2022-04-19T18:29:36.069Z",
            "Progress": "100%",
            "OwnerId": "012345678900",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-11111111111111111"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-restrictions

> When you tag public or shared resources, the tags you assign are
> available only to your AWS account; no other AWS account will have
> access to those tags. For tag-based access control to shared
> resources, each AWS account must assign its own set of tags to control
> access to the resource.